# jquery needs to use mvc model as parameter

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently working in ASP.NET MVC 4. I'm trying to use JQuery to render a specific part of my page in certain situations. For this I have written the following JQuery code:

```
var selectedLicense = '@Model.License';

        $.post("/Permission/LicenseConfigurationLabelOrCombobox", selectedLicense,
            function (responseText) { 
                $(".LicenseWizard").html(responseText);
            });
```

In my controller I have the following Action:

```
public String LicenseConfigurationLabelOrCombobox(LicenseWithCharacteristicsModel license)
        {
          //Do Stuff
        }
```

My action model remains to be empty though. In order to try something new, I did the following in my model:

```
public class PermissionLicenseConfigurationModel
    {
        public LicenseWithCharacteristicsModel License { get; set; }
        public string JsonLicense
        {
            get
            {
                return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(License);
            }
        }
    }
```

I updated my JQuery as well:

```
var selectedLicense = '@Model.JsonLicense';

        $.post("/Permission/LicenseConfigurationLabelOrCombobox", selectedLicense,
            function (responseText) { 
                $(".LicenseWizard").html(responseText);
            });
```

I can see that my JQuery uses a real serialized object, but my action model doesn't pick it up. The Id is always 0 and the values null.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by getting rid of this `JsonLicense` property from your view model:

```
public class PermissionLicenseConfigurationModel
{
    public LicenseWithCharacteristicsModel License { get; set; }
}
```

and then inside your view you could send the model as a JSON request to the controller:

```
var selectedLicense = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.License));
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("LicenseConfigurationLabelOrCombobox", "Permission")',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: JSON.stringify(selectedLicense),
    success: function(result) {
        $(".LicenseWizard").html(result);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't quite work. I've found this before, but on var selectedLicense = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.License)); I get syntax error on the ; and nothing more.

Comment: Where do you get this syntax error? In Visual Studio? Forget about it. Visual Studio Intellisense in Razor sucks badly. Run your application and you will see how fine it works :-)

Comment: Thanks for the hint on the intellisense. I didn't know VS sucks with jquery razor. On the other hand, I now got the following error: The name 'Json' does not exist in the current context. It refers directly to var selectedLicense = ...

Comment: Are you using Razor? The `Json` static class is defined inside the `System.Web.Helpers` assembly (same namespace). Normally this assembly should already be referenced in your project when you create a new ASP.NET MVC 3 application. Try fully qualifying it `System.Web.Helpers.Json.Encode(Model.License)`. As an alternative you could use `new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model.License)`. But in both cases keep them wrapped in a `@Html.Raw()` call.

Comment: I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4 with Razor Views. The System.Web.Helpers was indeed missing. After adding the reference to the project and writing the using-statement the error wasn't resolved. So I'm still stuck with thesame error.

Comment: Try fully qualifying the name. I can't help you anymore. You definitely have some problems referencing the assembly. Here's the link to the MSDN documentation for the Json class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.json(v=vs.111).aspx . Just create a new ASP.NET MVC 4 project from scratch using the Internet Template and you will see that in every view you can use this `Json` class.

Comment: I have accepted your answer as the current problem is something beyond the scope of my question. Thank you for the help.

Comment: After some trial and error I managed to find the problem. Visual Studio put my references copy local to false so I didn't get the .dll files. After changing this to true, the solution now fully works :)